# Is the Riemann Zeta function negative in the critical strip?

Tags: riemann-zeta

Just saw a question on "*how to prove that the Riemann Zeta function is negative in the critical strip*". What is meant by Zeta(s) < 0?

Does it mean that its real part is negative, or both real and imaginary parts are negative? I thought a complex function has no sign.

Comment: $\zeta(s) < 0\;$ for real $0\le s < 1$

Comment: Does 0 <=  s < 1 mean 0 <= Re(s) < 1 ? I am not familiar with inequalities in complex numbers

Comment: I mean real $s$

Comment: @Hass : if you want to understand $\zeta(s)$ maybe you should start studying a complex analysis course.  $\zeta(x)(x-1)$ is real for $x \in [0;\infty[$ and the functional equation tells us it has no pole (it is an entire function) hence it is real for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: According to the disc=ussion in the link below, it seems that there is no such a thing as a positive or negative complex numbers: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788164/positive-and-negative-complex-numbers