# Positive function for complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was curious whether it makes sense to talk about positive functions of a complex variable. I.e, does it make sense to talk about $f(z) > 0$, if $z$ is complex, say? As an example, what if $f(z) = \cos z + i \sin z$?

Answer (score 2):

Only if $f(z)$ is a real number. If it's a complex number, then no. See discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788164/positive-and-negative-complex-numbers#:%7E:text=The%20imaginary%20numbers%2C%200%2C%20and,are%20either%20positive%20or%20negative.).