# Showing that $i$ is neither negative nor positive

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, complex-numbers, ordered-fields

> Show that $i$ is neither negative nor positive.

*Proof:*

Assume that $i<0$

$i×i>0×i$    Since $i<0$

$i^{2}>0$

Since $i^{2}:=-1$

So,
$-1>0$ which doesn't hold and hence this is a contradiction to the fact.

Next, assume that $i>0$

$i×i>0×i$ since $i>0$

$i^{2}>0$

Since $i^{2}:=-1$

So, $-1>0$ which again doesn't hold and hence this is a contradiction to the fact.

This establishes the proof.

Is this valid proof?

Comment: So are you asking us to check your proof?

Comment: Yes, I have edited now.

Comment: Is there any other way to prove this? Also pls check my proof. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive and negative complex numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/788164/positive-and-negative-complex-numbers)

Comment: This is the standard way to show that there is no order in the complex numbers. You established it correctly. In particular, neither $i>0$ nor $i<0$ makes sense, hence $i$ is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: What I mean to ask that is i means iota neither negative nor positive? So I have proved it. I wanna know your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks sir Peter. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. More generally one might say:

Assume $k$ is an ordered field. Then every square must be non-negative, since $$x<0\implies x^2>0,x>0\implies x^2>0$$
for every $x\in k$. Thus $\mathbb{C}$ cannot be an ordered field, since it is algebraically closed and thus all elements are squares.